# Execute code only if there isn't the same number in an area of the page?

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

Basically, I want this:

```
The highest voted

answer 3 vote

The others

answer 1 vote
answer 2 vote
answer 1 vote
```

But I want to avoid this:

```
The highest voted

answer 3 vote

The others

answer 3 vote
answer 3 vote
answer 1 vote
```

Which doesn't make sense since there are other answers voted 3 below.

So I would like to create an if else statement like this:

```
(run this only if there isn't posts with the same amount of votes)

The highest voted

answer 3 vote

(end if)

The others

answer 3 vote
answer 3 vote
answer 1 vote
```

So in this case that code (the highest rated answer) shouldn't run.

I'm not sure if I should use php or jQuery for this.

The `The_votes();` function is outputting something like this: `+2 votes` so I can't use it directly since it has text.

I could make the comparisons based on divs or div classes.

Any suggestions about how to code this?

EDIT:

Example of PHP and HTML content of each answer:

```
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php bbp_reply_admin_links(); ?>
        <h4><?php bbp_topic_reply_count(); ?></h4>
        <div class="topic-like-count">
    <?php if(function_exists('the_votes')) { the_votes(); } ?>
```

I guess I have to get only the number from the_votes and do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you can't use `voting();` ?

Even if returns text like `+xx votes;` you can retrive the number with:

```
$voting = voting();
$votes = substr($voting,1,strpos($voting,' ')-1);
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not very familiar with php. After that what should I do?

Comment: i didn't get what output exactly you need. post an html example little